# What may be the problem with this beveling?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, vertices, bevel

I am working on a small project, but I cant seem to figure out why beveling is different on the sides on a symmetric object.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Picture of the object]

I'd like to bevel the shorter sides of it. These are rectangles, bit with 5 vetrices, because the corner of the top of the base connects to these ends.

One end and its beveling with clamb overlap and 1 segment:

[image: side vertices]

[image: bevel1]

Same for the other side:

[image: side2]

[image: bevel2]

These look like the same on the both sides, however the bevels are different.
I've checked for possible double-vetrices as well, and found none, so I have no idea what may be wrong here.

Could anyone please help me bevel these sides? I want them to look similar to these corners, where only the sides are curved:

[image: example bevel]

Comment: Have you checked if your faces are flipped?

Comment: I haven't. I did a quick googleing and found out that the problem was that one side was indeed facing inwards. Thank you very much for the help!